# Is a coin fair?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, estimation, inference

> Is a coin fair ? In other words, does a coin come up $50$% heads ? If a coin is unfair, then it would not come up $50$% heads.

**My thoughts :**

let's first identify the population and the parameter

Comment: This is already answered within this one: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95643/you-observe-k-heads-out-of-n-tosses-is-the-coin-fair/95684#95684

Comment: this not the same question that i asked

Comment: Yes, it is. The answer of that question applies to yours.

Comment: Which coin are you talking about ? What is the population mentionned in your thoughts ?

Comment: The question itself maybe not the same, but your question is nevertheless answered within the answers to that other question!  see the answer byZhang Tschao.  Your Q is also answered a lot other times other places here, time to say stop. Search for "you can't bias a coin" here and elsewhere.